# How to change default page print size in chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, pdf

Is it possible to change the default page print size in Chrome? I'm printing the webpage to a pdf file and it seems that the size is letter. I want to be able to change that to A4. Or if there are any chrome extensions that you know that will make this possible.
I've seen one extension but it cannot print the page to pdf since what I'm trying to print is on localhost.

Comment: I think it has to do with the default for the printer.

Comment: so does it mean that even if it appears to be letter size on the pdf it will be converted to A4 when I print it directly?

Comment: I believe that you set the default paper size for the printer (in this case A4) and then chrome will take that value. It will **not** print a different size than what it says

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the regular `Print` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> option, try using the `Print using system dialog` option <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

You can then select the printer you wish to use, and click on `Preferences` to change the paper size and other printing options.

Answer (score 0):

**2014-10-05 Edit**: Chrome 37 now has a 'Paper size' option in its print dialog, allowing to choose between A3, A4, Letter, Legal and Tabloid.

---

To confirm what soandos wrote, on Mac OS (10.6.8), Chrome (32.x) will take the Default paper size, as set in the 'Print & Fax' preference pane ('B5' in the example below).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: However this does not address the OP who asked for a way to change the _defaults_. (Chrome does not seem to remember these settings across sessions, nor does it honor the system preferences for default paper. My system default is letter, but Chrome seems to revert back to 4x6 when I restart. Even in 2021.

Answer (score -3):

In the Settings page of Chrome, click "Show advanced settings..." Then under "Web content" you can choose a default font size. You should note which size you have before changing it, because you'll probably want to change it back after printing.

Change the setting, and refresh the page, and preview in print. When you are done, change your settings back to what they were... unless you always prefer especially large fonts.

Comment: The question was about paper size, not font size.